# How to improve a ADT?

Tags: python

I am going to design and implement an ADT representing an unfair set.
A set is an ADT which follows the same rules as real sets, new items are added to the back of the set (pushing) and old items are removed from the front of the set (popping).

When I attempt to add a value which already exists in the set nothing happens. This is the standard expected behavior for a set. The difference between a normal set and the unfair set I will submit is that when I push an uppercase letter onto the set it should be added regardless of whether it already exists in the set.

The upper content is the question I'm facing.

The code I tried to write:

```
class Set:
class Full(Exception):
    pass
class Empty(Exception):
    pass


def __init__(self, data=None):

    """ Show the set base and the data are inside the dictionary"""
    self.data = {} # the dictionary of the set
    if data != None: 
        if len(data) != len(set(data)):
            data = set(data)
        for d in data:
            self.data[d] = d

def add(self, value):

    """This function show how to add value in to the set, if value
       in the set, it will return a message and stop the process. Else,
       The new value will add into the set"""

    if value in self.data.keys():
        return 'This word is already in set'
    else:
        self.data[value] = value # value == key, so it only show the value is store

def remove(self, value):

    """This function is use for removing value from the set,
       if the value is not in the set, it will return a message"""

    if value not in self.data.keys():
        return 'No value found in the set' 
    self.data.pop(value)

def size(self):

    """ Returns the number of values currently stored in the 
        set """

    return len(self.data.keys())

def is_in(self, value):

    """ This funiction use for test is the current value save in
        teh set, if yes it will return true. Else return false."""

    if i in self.data.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_in(self, value):

    """ This funiction use for test is the current value save in
        teh set, if yes it will return true. Else return false."""

    if i in self.data.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The functions I want to run in the program:

- `size` should return the current size of the unfair set.
- `add` should add a given character to the unfair set.
- `remove` should remove a given character from the unfair set, in cases where uppercase characters are stored multiple times then one of them should be removed.
- `is_in` should indicate if a given character is currently stored in the unfair set.

How can I improve them without using any `set` or `frozenset` in python library and store at least 100 words?

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of your previous question, now deleted, which had multiple comments asking for clarification. You do not seem to have responded to those comments by actually adding useful information. Your "unfair set" is still completely unclear. Please pay attention to those previous comments and make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have a thing which behaves one way ( as a set ) with one kind of value ( anything which is not an uppercase letter ), and another way ( as a bag ) with another kind of input ( anything which is an uppercase letter ).

The simplest way of solving this kind of problem is to aggregate instances of the types which implement the two behaviours into one object, and provide an interface which dispatches to the instances based on the value. For example, it should be possible to use a set and a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and choose between them based on whether the value is upper case. You also might be able to get away with just having a counter or dict, and choosing to decrement or completely remove the entry based on the value.

> real sets, new items are added to the back of the set (pushing) and old items are removed from the front of the set (popping).

The usual use of set data structures do not have a 'front' or 'back' as they are unordered. The phrase 'real sets' doesn't make much sense - they are an *abstract* data type, after all.